# adjusting the object result Javascript

Tags: javascript, object

I have two objects. First object old object. Second object new object. As a result I want to combine these objects. How do I go the easy way.
Example:

```
// old object
{
  name: 'exapmle name',
  surname: 'example surname',
  number: '123456'
}


// new object
{
  name: 'change name',
  surname: 'change surname',
  number: null
}

// result 
{
  name: 'change name',
  surname: 'change surname',
  number: '123456'
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/global_objects/object/assign

Comment: Update.. not fix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) can help for this purpose.

```js
const old = { name: 'exapmle name', surname: 'example surname', number: '123456' };
const newObj = { name: 'change name', surname: 'change surname', };

const result = { ...old, ...newObj };

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I was not. I updated the subject.

Comment: Update... not fix.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.assign` as so:

```
oldObj = {
  name: 'exapmle name',
  surname: 'example surname',
  number: '123456'
}

newObj = {
  name: 'change name',
  surname: 'change surname',
}

result = Object.assign({}, newObj, oldObj)

result => {name: "exapmle name", surname: "example surname", number: "123456"}
```

Comment: I was not. I updated the subject.